# Kendo UI Grid DropdownList, EditorViewData and EditorTemplateName not posting ViewData

Tags: kendo-grid

Kind Attention:-

- I am working with very simple model with Kendo UI Grid which has 2 dropdownlist
- I have 2 model classes (a)Category (b)Products

  ```
              public class Category
          {
              public int CategoryID { get; set; }
              public string Name { get; set; }
              public string Address { get; set; }
              public System.DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
              public string ListA { get; set; }
              public string ListB { get; set; }
              public int Count { get; set; }
              public decimal Price { get; set; }
              public bool decision { get; set; }
              public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
          }

              public class Product
          {
              public string Person { get; set; }
              public int ProductID { get; set; }
              public bool Chk { get; set; }
              public decimal Balance { get; set; }
              public decimal Deposit { get; set; }
              public decimal Adjustment { get; set; }
              public decimal NewBalance { get; set; }
              [UIHint("AccountList"), Required]
              public string Account { get; set; }
              [UIHint("VaryDDL")]
              public string VaryDDList { get; set; }
          }
  ```
- The 2 dropdownlist in the grid, 1st ddl- Account which is using columns.ForeignKeys
  along with "ViewData" list with editortemplate "AccountList.cshtml"
- Another ddl(PROBLEMATIC ONE- Marked with ***)VaryDDL which is also columns.ForeignKeys using   EditorViewDate annd EditorTemplate name
- I am using columns.ForeignKeys along with EditorTemplateName to get these dropdownList
  @model IEnumerable(GridInForm.Models.Product) - Model used in the view

  ```
              <div>
                              @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Products)
                          .Name("Products")
                          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Chk).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' ${ Chk == true ? checked='checked' : ''} disabled />");
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Person).ClientTemplate("<a href='\\#'>#= Person #</a>").ClientFooterTemplate("Total: #=count#");
                              columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Account, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TestVDt"], "Value", "Text");

                              ***columns.ForeignKey(p => p.VaryDDList, Model.Products, "ProductID", "Person")
                              .EditorViewData(new { ProductID = "#=ProductID#" })
                              .EditorTemplateName("VaryDDL");***

                              columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Hidden();
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Balance).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', Balance) #");
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Deposit).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', Deposit) #");
                              columns.Bound(p => p.Adjustment).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', Adjustment) #").ClientFooterTemplate("Total: #=sum#");
                              columns.Bound(p => p.NewBalance).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', NewBalance) #").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c}', Deposit + Adjustment) #");
                          })
                          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                              .Events(e => e.Change("TestScript"))
                              .Model(model =>
                              {
                                  model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
                                  model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
                                  model.Field(p => p.Person).Editable(false);
                                  model.Field(p => p.Balance).Editable(false);
                                  model.Field(p => p.Deposit).Editable(false);
                                  model.Field(p => p.NewBalance).Editable(false);
                              })
                              .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                              {
                                  aggregates.Add(p => p.Person).Count();
                                  aggregates.Add(p => p.Adjustment).Sum();
                              })
                              .Batch(true)
                              .ServerOperation(false)
                          ))
                          </div>
  ```

editortemplatename view data (VaryDDL.cshtml)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
.DataValueField("Value")
.DataTextField("Text")
.OptionLabel("Select")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("ChkProduct", "Home", new { ProductID = ViewData["ProductID"] }))
)
```

)

Controller action of the above :

```
        public JsonResult ChkProduct(int prodid)
    {
            if (prodid == 1)
            {
                List<SelectListItem> Slt1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
                SelectListItem sltLst1 = new SelectListItem();

                Slt1 = new List<SelectListItem> 
                {
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV1", Value="1" }, 
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV2", Value="2" }, 
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV3", Value="3" }
                };

                return Json(Slt1.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                List<SelectListItem> Slt2 = new List<SelectListItem>();

                Slt2 = new List<SelectListItem> 
                {
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV4", Value="1" }, 
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV5", Value="2" }, 
                     new SelectListItem { Text="VV6", Value="3" }
                };

                return Json(Slt2.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
   }
```

- For the VaryDLL I am passing the ProductId as ViewData to the Editortemplate "VaryDLL"
  which is nothing but the kendo ui dropdownlist which has a read method which takes the
  productid from the view data
  AND based on the productId I am just load list item (if productid=1 then 1st list item     so on...
- I AM TRYING TO DO SMALL PROTOTYPE COLUMNS.FOREIGNKEYS, EDITORVIEWDATA AND  EDITORTEMPLATENAME  FUNCTIONALITY
- BUT somehow the read method is not working 
  (a)I mean when i put a break point it is not stop there
  (b)And in the UI the dropdownlist will keep spinning

**PLEASE LET ME KNOW WHAT WRONG I AM DOING AND IS THERE ANY OTHER BETTER APPROACH**
Kindly post some code....thanks!!